# Choosing the most idiomatic sentence

Tags: word-usage, idioms

Which one is more idiomatic?

> My greatest achievement is the first prize in a modeling competition.

OR

> My greatest achievement is winning the first prize in a modeling competition.

Comment: When you ask which is more popular, you're asking which is more likely to be used?

Comment: I wouldn't say that either is *popular*. Perhaps *my achievement was first prize*, but even that sounds a little strange. Far more likely is simply *I won first prize* or *I came in first* (depending on the competition).

Comment: @KillingTime Yes I am.

Comment: @JasonBassford Thank you. I have modified the sentence a bit. Does it look less strange now?

Comment: 'achievement' and 'winning' are both activities.  'prize' is more likely a physical object.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a question of popularity or idiomaticity; they're just different ways of saying the same thing.

No-one is going to frown upon

> My greatest achievement is the first prize in a modelling competition.

Nor will they frown  upon

> My greatest achievement is winning the first prize in a modelling competition.

It is quite clear that  the first sentence means 'I won first prize'.  Personally, I would remove the word 'the' in both sentences if you want to be completely idiomatic.

The verb 'winning' is superfluous; it neither adds nor takes from the meaning.

My sentence of choice would be

> My greatest achievement is  first prize in a modelling competition.